# Movie redraws contour lines

Tags: image, matlab, contour, movie

I made a contourfm plot with white contour lines.

I used `'LineColor', 'white'` but in a movie, the white lines propagate after each image instead of redrawing. The colors on the image itself redraws automatically. What am I doing wrong?

Also, when viewing the image, it shows up small on the top left hand corner. A similar script before did not cause this issue. Anyone know why?

```
% Create movie
nFrames = 893; % Number of frames
for k = 1:nFrames % Create movie 
    % Eqdconic script    
    % Define figure and axes
    fg1 = figure(1);
    axesm('MapProjection','eqdconic', 'MapParallels', [], 'MapLatLimit',[-79.625 -59.625],'MapLonLimit',[190.625 250.625]) 
    framem on; gridm on; mlabel on; plabel on; hold all; 

    % Plot data
    frame = dataSST_movie(:,:,k);
    image = contourfm(Y,X,frame, 'LineColor', 'white'); % Change contour lines to white

    mov(k) = getframe(gcf);
end

close(gcf)

% % Save as AVI file 
movie2avi(mov, 'SST_20110101to20130611_0.25grid.avi', 'compression', 'none', 'fps', 4);
```

The `image = contourfm()` part is what I'm talking about; is there some command like `redraw` that I need to use?

Answer (score 0):

Just use clf before `end`. As for the size issue, check MapLatLimit and MapLonLimit. If they are correct, it should work.